# How to make the image of specific html div or how can I take screenshot of specific area in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a specific div tag or specific defined area on button click event in javascript. I try canvas's method but it only makes the image of canvas data if any other data is there on the canvas area it ignores the other data and background image etc.
Following is the desired image that I want and captured images using canvas. Any help to get my actual image whenever I click on the button.

**Desired:**
[Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtDC5.png)

**Captured through canvas.toDataURL("image/png"):**
[Captured through canvas.toDataURL()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3IPQ.png)

Comment: The mentioned solution is working fine with v0.4.1 but it is not working with the latest version(1.0.0-rc.5) of html2canvas. Though it did not give any error but not give the desired output.